# Sorting gridview - can't find column

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview

Relative newbie here. Discovered that I have to write an event handler to handle sorting of my data from an objectdatasource. Found a lot of references to code like what's below, but when the code runs I get the message "**Cannot find column xxx**" where xxx is the name of the column I'm trying to sort on.

I've verified that e.SortExpression is returning the proper column name, but the problem appears to be in the 2nd line below, where I try to create a datatable (dt) from the GridView1.Datasource. The value of dt after this statement is 'nothing', so the rest of the code fails.

Also, I'm listing most of the gridview definition in case that's helpful.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_Sorting(sender As Object, e As GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles GridView1.Sorting
    Dim dt As Data.DataTable = New Data.DataTable(GridView1.DataSource)
    If Not dt Is Nothing Then
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

ASPX snippet:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" CellPadding="4" 
        EmptyDataText="No records found for your search" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" Width="930px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Size="12px" AllowSorting="True">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustName" HeaderText="CustName" 
                SortExpression="CustName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustType" HeaderText="CustType" 
                SortExpression="CustType" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Addr1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Addr1") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Addr1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="ContactName" 
                SortExpression="ContactName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastContactDate" HeaderText="LastContact" SortExpression="LastContactDate" dataformatstring="{0:d}" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustSince" HeaderText="CustSince" 
                SortExpression="CustSince" dataformatstring="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status"  
                SortExpression="Status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Source" HeaderText="Source" 
                SortExpression="Source" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RelMgr" HeaderText="RelMgr" 
                SortExpression="RelMgr" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RelMgrInfo">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:HyperLink ID="RelMgrEmailLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("RelMgrEmail", "mailto:{0}")%>' Text='<%# Eval("RelMgrEmail") + "<br>" + Eval("RelMgrPhone")%>  '> </asp:HyperLink>
                 </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to handle the sorting event if you work with the ObjectDataSource. Instead, set the SortParameterName to a string (like "OrderBy") and augment your business method signature that ObjectDataSource uses to retrieve data with this parameter:

```
public IEnumerable<Whatever> Retrieve( string OrderBy, ... other arguments ) ...
```

The grid will pass the parameter value to the ODS and then ODS will pass it to your method.

Comment: Wiktor, I understand what you're saying, but can't get it to work. I added a parameter to <SelectParameters>, then referenced that parameter in the ODS's SortParameterName, and finally added a corresponding parameter to my SELECT method statement. But since I commented out my sorting method in the code-behind, I now get an error: "The GridView 'GridView1' fired event Sorting which wasn't handled" which is what started me down this road in the first place.

Comment: First, enable grid view sorting by setting EnableSorting to true. Then, add the sort parameter name to your object data source. And then, remove the handler for sorting event, you don't need it. If you still have trouble, let me know, I'll point you to a working example.

Comment: Yep, I had already done all those things, Wiktor. I could use that example. Thanks!

Comment: That would be one of these http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/~wzychla/ra2829/example3a.zip or http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/~wzychla/ra2829/example3.zip, can't verify now as I am on a mobile device which doesn't allow me to peek into zips. Anyway, you should have a pageable and sortable gridview/listview with objectdatasource there. I use these examples during my asp.net lectures.

Comment: Verified, the second example is the one.